# Message: mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli

Hi in my codeigniter application when I try to connect my MySql database the following error has occured.

> Message: mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): A connection attempt
>   failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a
>   period of time, or established connection failed because connected
>   host has failed to respond.

I am using Windows 10 system

XAMPP v3.2.2

PHP Version 7.2.4

Phpmyadmin 4.8.1

Codeigniter Configuration setting

```
    'dsn'      => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'XXXXXX',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => 'ss_',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'development'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt'  => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
```

Some people suggest that change the host name to 127.0.0.1, but that didn't work for me,some of them suggest to edit the `System32\drivers\etc\host` settings but I did not get any positive result, here I enclose the host settings also

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
```

Comment: Just in case (been there, done that): have you started the mysql service in xampp?

Comment: In xampp you need to start the mysql service on port 3306 just check that

Comment: hi i checked that mysql service is on port 3306